# Different queryset, same result

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm currently learning Model Manager and Custom Queryset. While trying to understand the implementation of it, I somehow just don't get how the difference between these two calls. I like to include the all() because its more understandable. However I would like to know if there's any difference.

```
1. Post.objects.all().filter(status=1).order_by('-updated')
2. Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-updated')

>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from blog.models import Post
>>> user= User.objects.filter(username='chair').first()
>>> Post.objects.filter(author= user)
<PostQuerySet [<Post: 111 updateeee>, <Post: 22222>, <Post: draftdraft>]>
>>> Post.objects.all().filter(author= user)
<PostQuerySet [<Post: 111 updateeee>, <Post: 22222>, <Post: draftdraft>]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same. You can inspect the resulting SQL query that will be done and see that they are actually the same.

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> qs_1 = User.objects.all().filter(username="Me").order_by('-id')
>>> qs_2 = User.objects.filter(username="Me").order_by('-id')
>>> print(qs_1.query)
SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."username" = Me ORDER BY "auth_user"."id" DESC
>>> print(qs_2.query)
SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."username" = Me ORDER BY "auth_user"."id" DESC
```

Since you are in the topic of managers and querysets, note that as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects):

> Note that `delete()` is the only QuerySet method that is not exposed on
> a Manager itself. This is a safety mechanism to prevent you from
> accidentally requesting `Entry.objects.delete()`, and deleting all the
> entries. If you do want to delete all the objects, then you have to
> explicitly request a complete query set: `Entry.objects.all().delete()`

So it is safe to assume that all `QuerySet` functionality other than `delete()` e.g. `all()`, `filter()`, `get()`, etc. are available directly from the manager `Model.objects.<method>`.